# How to stack up many vars and functions in EvalMath class (PHP)?

Tags: php, math, eval

Sorry my bad english.

I'm using the EvalMath Class (http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html) to build a chemistry functions interpreter.

The class work fine to:

```
$math->evaluate("xx = 2");
$math->evaluate("yy = 2");
$math->evaluate("zz = xx + yy");
echo $math->evaluate("zz"); //print 4
```

But I need this:

```
$math->evaluate("xx = 2");
$math->evaluate("zz = xx + yy"); //yy is undefined
$math->evaluate("yy = 2");
echo $math->evaluate("zz"); //empty
```

My vars and functions are in a database, are hundreds, so i can't specify the functions order.
So, i need accumulate the variables values to calculate only at a specific time (in the end).

I think the answer must lie in the use of the '$this->v[]' variable in class, but I do not have sufficient knowledge to fix it.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the class it would appear that the value is evaluated at the point you call `->evaluate`.

If you really don't care about efficiency surround your code in a loop and call it as many times as you have statements (this number would only be for the worst case where the last is the only one accepted each time, to improve it you could record those that failed in a queue, re-adding to the queue if they fail and continuing until empty).

```
for ($i =0; $i <3; $i++){
    $math->evaluate("xx = 2");
    $math->evaluate("zz = xx + yy"); //yy is undefined
    $math->evaluate("yy = 2");
}
echo $math->evaluate("zz"); //empty
```

You will get errors so you could use `$math->suppress_errors = true;` before calling it. Please note this is hideously inefficient, but probably the only way if you want to still use this class without modifying it.

If all of the statements are this simple you could probably implement your own parser pretty simply and store each of the definitions in a map and writing an evaluate method which recursively evaluates in the end.

```
$c["xx"] = new literal(2);
$c["zz"] = new plus("xx", "yy", $c);
$c["yy"] = new literal(2);


class plus {
    var $a;
    var $b;
    var $array;

    function __construct($a, $b, &$c) {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->array = &$c;
    }

    public function evaluate() {
        return 
                $this->array[$this->a]->evaluate() 
                +
                $this->array[$this->b]->evaluate();
    }

}

class literal {
    var $a;
    function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
    public function evaluate() {
        return $this->a;
    }
}

echo $c["zz"]->evaluate();
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, David! The 'for' solution is the best for my case.  The functions using  many complex operators, so i can't use your second solution, but it will be useful to others situations. Thanks again!